# How do I retrieve house number in magento street value via soap?

Tags: php, string, magento

I have magento, and I'm posting a request via the soap v2 api to get the address of an order.

With that I get the following object which contains the street name + housenumber(God knows why these fields are not seperate...)

```
$shipping_address->street = "4th avenue 108";
```

Now what I want is to have the housenumber 108.

How do I get this house number without getting the 4?
(if someone has a more reliable function/piece of code than the one I post below, please feel free to post it.)

Answer (score 0):

What you basically have to do is check for the first number occurence with a space in front of it.
This way you minimse the risk of fetching the wrong number:

```
// Code by Michael Dibbets
// shared under creative commons Attribution 3.0 Unported (CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ )
$value = "4th street26";
$spl = str_split($value);
$pos = 0;
$location = 0;
// simple loop to find the first character with space + integer
foreach($spl as $char)
    {
    if(is_numeric($char) && $spl[$pos-1]==' ') 
        {
        $location = $pos;
        break;
        }
    $pos++;
    }
// If we didn't encounter the space + integer combination
if(!$location)
    {
    // is the last character an integer? Assume that the last numbers are house numbers
    if(is_numeric($spl[count($spl)-1]))
        {
        for($c=count($spl)-1;$c>0;$c--)
            {
            if(is_numeric($spl[$c]))
                {
                continue;
                }
            else
                {
                $location = $c+1;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
if($location)
    {
    $street = substr($value,0,$location);
    $number = substr($value,$location);
    }
else
    {
    $street = $value;
    $number = null;
    }
// echoing the results. The number should appear after the dash.
echo $street .  ' - ' . $number;
```